# Formatting Scala files in Visual Studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am working on a legacy code base where someone configured the tab to be 3 spaces and saved the files.

I want to reformat the files so that each file is indented with 4 spaces.

Can VSCode do that? When I select a file content and select format from edit menu it says no code formatter for .scala files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>Sounds like you might want to try [the Scalafmt extension for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=gabro.vscode-scalafmt).</s>

EDIT:

I can't delete this answer as it is the accepted one, but the answer of @pme seems to be the correct one now.

Comment: oh yes. that's exactly what I needed. didn't know it already existed. thanks!

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer is **deprecated**! See [vscode-scalafmt](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=gabro.vscode-scalafmt).

Use **[Metals](https://scalameta.org/metals/)** instead.